# BOOT_COMPLETED sporadically not sent on bootup

Tags: android, boot, bootcompleted

I am using BOOT_COMPLETED Intent to start a service of mine.
However, like 1 time in 5, the BOOT_COMPLETED intent is not sent, thus my service fails to start. I have tried using WakefulBroadcastReceiver and other things but I can't understand why it sometimes isn't sent. I mean the device is working, you can connect to it via adb and so on, it's just that BOOT_COMPLETED is not sent. Does anyone have an idea about what is going on?

I am on Android 4.4.4 Kitkat. I am aware of the stopped-state issue, however I have used Xposed to disable that and it still doesn't work so it ought to be something else.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Manifest added:

```
<receiver android:name=".services.ShutdownReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In created  class :

```
public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
         Intent i = new Intent(context, GPSService.class);
         context.startService(i);
    }
}
```